# how to fix Incorrect Permission Assignment For Critical Resources issue when you don't know the actual permission

Tags: java, spring

I am getting Incorrect Permission Assignment For Critical Resources security issue in spring project with every file object. It's saying that we need to set permission for the file but I am working on some old project and don't know about the actual permission so how can I set default permission.

1. File file = path.toFile();
2. File directory = new File(location);

Comment: What are you using to get that "issue"?  What is the "it" that is saying this? What does this have to do with the 2 Java statements in your question?  You need to clarify your question if you want meaningful answers.

Comment: I am getting this issue with Checkmarx tool while scanning project.

Answer (score -1):

```
file.setReadable(true);
file.setWritable(false, true);
```

and

```
directory.setReadable(true);
directory.setWritable(false, true);
```